# Ubuntu 9.04 will not shut down

Tags: shutdown, ubuntu-9.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 9.04 on my s/s, which already had Windows XP installed. When I shut down Ubuntu 9.04, it halts with the message on black screen.... `[395.916368] system halted.` Even after waiting for a long time, it still does not shut down on its own. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your system to automatically power-off, not just shut down the O/S, likely there are some ACPI issues between the O/S and the motherboard. Try adjusting the ACPI parameters in the system BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

When a linux system "halts" it's ok to power off manually.

Is the system halting after you have just installed it, or is it halting every time you tell it to shut down?

What is helpful to know is how you are shutting the computer down.  Are you doing it through the menu in GNOME (your desktop environment) or are you at the command line and telling the system to shutdown.

If you are at the command line, then you want to shut down using this command:

```
?> sudo shutdown -h now
```

That will both shutdown Ubuntu and turn off the power to the computer.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for ur ans., i will try shut down by giving command u told. Actually s/s halt every time i tell it shut down, I m shutting down through the menu in GNOMe. Can u pls tell me why it halts every time i tell it to shut down?

Comment: Hey i jst gave the command 
sudo shutdown -h now
The system again halted as it used to halt before. What should i do now?

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from here. It seems that some program is interrupting the shutdown process.  Try 'sudo shutdown -P now' and see what happens. This is supposed to force a powerdown.